# Regex validate string with comma-separated

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm using JavaScript, I need to accept only string or string with comma-separated if there has more string.

My code is as follows

```
const text = 'AB1234567';
const hasText = text.match(/^([A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{7}(,\s)?)+$/);
```

My code test is as follows

```
// first test
const text = 'AB1234567'; // output: 'AB1234567'
const hasText = text.match(/^([A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{7}(,\s)?)+$/); // is good.

// second test
const text = 'AB1234567, '; // output: 'AB1234567, '
const hasText = text.match(/^([A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{7}(,\s)?)+$/); // is good, but I dont need this.

// third test
const text = 'AB1234567, AB1234568'; // output: 'AB1234567, AB1234568'
const hasText = text.match(/^([A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{7}(,\s)?)+$/); // is good, I need this.

// fourth test
const text = 'AB1234567, AB1234568, '; // output: 'AB1234567, AB1234568, '
const hasText = text.match(/^([A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{7}(,\s)?)+$/); // is good, but I dont need this.
```

How can I accept only the correct value?

Correct values is first test and third test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex will accept strings that end with a comma and a space, which apparently you don't want.  So, let's make the regex enforce that the string doesn't end that way:

```
text.match(/^([A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{7},\s)*[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{7}$/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regex to just accept the strings.

```js
// first test
let text = 'AB1234567'; // output: 'AB1234567'
let regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g
let hasText = text.match(regex); // is good.
console.log(hasText);
// second test
 text = 'AB1234567, '; // output: 'AB1234567, '
 hasText = text.match(regex); // is good, but I dont need this.
console.log(hasText);
// third test
 text = 'AB1234567, AB1234568'; // output: 'AB1234567, AB1234568'
 hasText = text.match(regex); // is good, I need this.
console.log(hasText);
// fourth test
 text = 'AB1234567, AB1234568, '; // output: 'AB1234567, AB1234568, '
 hasText = text.match(regex); 
console.log(hasText);
```